# after getting ip from centos, that ip is not connecting with putty in unix

Tags: unix, centos7, putty

I am trying connect the IP with putty, which is generated in cent OS 
But that IP is not connecting in putty.
Please someone help regarding that.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you connecting on the correct port (assuming TCP)?

Comment: what to you want to connect to ? vm, cloud instance,standalone server? what os? how are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

-Ensure you have the right port forwarding rules set up on your VM and connect to the correct port.

-Make sure ONBOOT=yes on /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/enp0sX file.

In this case you'd connect to port 2222.